# Windows Mobile Application exiting unexpectedly

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-mobile, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a fairly complex c# application that runs on Windows Mobile 5.0 and later.  It includes code that uses SQL CE, updates GPS coordinatess on a seperate thread, and also uses Microsoft Sync Framework in a seperate thread to sync to a server in the background.  The application generally runs fairly well, but every so often out in production, the application main window disappears.
I have a code like to the following in the Program.cs file:

```
static class Program
{
    private static NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Program");
    [MTAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Info("Program V {0} starting.", Utility.AppVersion);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
            _logger.Info("After Application.Run().");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException("Exception occurred.", ex);
        }
    }

    static void MobileDevice_Hibernate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.Info("Hibernate was received.");
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.ErrorException("Unhandled exception was thrown", e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    }
}
```

I see the starting info log as expected, and when the application disappears, I also get the `After Application.Run()` message.  But I do not get the messages logged in the MainForm.Closing event, so it seems that it is never called.  I also do not get any exception logged from either the exception handler around the `Application.Run` or the `UnhandledException` handler.  I thought it might be related to running low/out of memory and that is why I have the `Hibernate` event wired up as well.  But I do not get the Hibernate event either.

Any help, or suggestions would be appreciated as I am out of ideas and things to check.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the risk of stating the obvious, something is crashing your app that is preventing your Closing Event from firing.

For your items that run on separate threads (most likely suspects), can you create class containers for them that implement `IDisposable`? Then, you could place `NLog` references in your `Dispose()` methods to record your data.

```
public class FirstClass : IDisposable {

  private bool isDisposed;

  public FirstClass() {
    isDisposed = false;
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    _logger.Info("FirstClass is done.");
    isDisposed = true;
  }

  public void Method1() {
    while (!isDisposed) {
      // your code here
    }
  }

}
```

You would need to create a way so that `_logger` can be accessible to this class, however.

Bugs in threads can be hard to catch.

Comment: Hi jp2code, not sure I follow your suggestion.  Anyway, all main functions on seperate threads have `try/catch` blocks around them, and I do not get anything logged from there.  Also, will the exception not marshall up to the main thread and then be caught there or in the '`UnhandledException` handler ?

Comment: Hey DJ. I added a little code example that creates a disposable class. In the example, `Method1()` would be whatever you use to thread with. When it is done and your class is destroyed, your `_logger` function would be called.